# How to sort a 2 arrays(char and int) that need to be linked together

Tags: c++

I have a program that counts how many time a letter has been used and I need it to have it sorted so it goes from the start of the alphabet . How can I do it?
P.S. I tried everything i know . (I'm still learning in school and my teacher did not care about how we do it so he did not explain how to do it correctly , said something that we did not learn , and we will learn it later , but this needs to be still done.

I tried to do sort and other sorting methods but I cant link them up together so it shows the right number of uses like x at first was 3 (right answer) at the end it shows 2 and etc.

```
main ()
{
    ifstream tekstas; 
    ofstream rezultatas;
    tekstas.open ("tekstas.txt");
    char sim, raides [60]; 
    int n, kuri, kiekis [60], i ,j; 
    bool tinka, yra; 
    n = -1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        raides[i] = ' '; 
        kiekis[i] = 0;
    }

    while ( tekstas.get (sim) ) 
    {
       kuri = 0; 
       tinka = ((sim != ' ') && (sim != '.') && (sim != ',') && (sim != '(') && (sim != ')'));
       tinka = ( tinka && (sim != '-') && (sim != ';') && (sim != '+'));        
       if ( tinka )
       {
           yra = false; 
           for ( int i = 0; i <= n; i++) if ( raides [i] == sim ) 
           {
               kuri = i; 
               yra = true; 
           }
           if ( yra ) kiekis[kuri]++; 
           else
           {
               n++; 
               raides[n] = sim;
               kiekis[n]++; 
           }
       }
    }

    rezultatas.open ("rez.txt"); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
        rezultatas << raides[i] << "   " << kiekis[i] << endl; 

     rezultatas.close ();
     tekstas.close (); 
     return 0; 
}
```

I expect the output should be linked up ( if like in the `tekstas.txt` file was 3 x's so in the end file there should be 3 x's) and so the letters go in alphabetic order.

Comment: 1) Why aren't you using [`std::map<char, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), to count the frequency table? That would make the logic, of the program, way easier. 2) In addition to `std::map`, you can use [`std::isalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) to check if the character is alphanumeric.

Comment: My crystall ball tells me you're using TurboC++. If you do, then stop doing so. If not accept my apologies and forget this comment.

Comment: Well I wrote this only with the things I know and map or isalnum I don't know how to use them.

Comment: @Qikee `#include <map>...std::map<char, int> themap; ... if (isalnum(char_read_in)) themap[char_read_in]++;` -- That is essentially the entire program.

Comment: @Qikee then learn them now. `isalnum` is most basic c/c++ stuff and `std::map` is very handy and powerful and will save you a lot of time is this project as well as in future projects. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try to do it with map and isalnum

Comment: If teachers only gave assignments that you already knew how to do, what use would school be?

Comment: @user4581301 Emh I think that we should've get atleast some explanation but we did not get any.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am embarrassed to ask , but I don't find a way to use map becouse of a constant expression and a array in raides[60]  (Letters [60]) and kiekis [60] (quantity [60]) how can I convert them or smtg like that?

Comment: You don't need any arrays.  The `map` stores all the information.

Comment: Please see this [demonstration program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a11221dbcc01fba6).